# Forming SFTP Connection in Azure Data Factory - failed to negotiate key exchange algorithm

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, sftp

I am setting up a linked service in Azure Data Factory using an SFTP connection to a SmartFile.com site. In setting up the connection, I am receiving Error code 22665 "Failed to negotiate key exchange algorithm."

I am attempting to connecting via basic auth (username and password), and I have no trouble connecting this way via desktop FTP client. I have tried with and without "SSH Host Key Finger-print" using both SHA-256 and MD5 formats for the fingerprint identifier within ADF.

I have validated between ADF and SmartFile documentation and they support a number of the same SSH ciphers, though I'm not sure if I can force ADF to pick which one to use. Based on documentation, it seems like they should be using the same expected algorithms for connection. I have enabled the "allowKeyboardInteractiveAuth" setting in ADF in case the SFTP site is prompting for manual password entry upon log in but that has not made a difference. Whenever logging in via desktop FTP client, I do get a password prompt, but again this hasn't made a difference for the linked service.

There should be not need to use SSH private key for connectivity, as only basic authentication is required (and works via FTP client). There seems to be some level of disconnect with ADF goes to the SFTP site and provide username/password. I am able to form an FTP linked service to the site via ADF and it works fine (albeit very slow and unsecured). Any thoughts on other things to try or technical maneuvers would be helpful.

Comment: I set this up frequently with "Disable SSH host key Validation" and "Basic" and have never encountered such an issue. What integration runtime are you using? Are you specifying port 22?

Comment: I'm using standard Azure IR. Yes, port 22 is specified as an SFTP connection. Any combination of configurations I'm seeing "Failed to negotiate key exchange algorithm.".

Comment: I've got the same problem when connecting to an Azure storage account via "SFTP (preview)"

Answer (score 2):

I have a ticket open on this.
ADF uses a 5+ year old library.  It only supports the following KEX. This is verbatim from support
"ADF leverages SSH.NET  to connect SFTP server, the nuget version is 2016.1.0, the supported key exchange algorithms  include:

diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256

diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1

diffie-hellman-group14-sha1

diffie-hellman-group1-sha1"

The end result is that support put in a feature request to the Product team but there is no ETA for resolution.